# cts:highlight function throwing error when wrapper element applying on the search result

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am applying `cts:highlight` function on the search result when i am wrapping search result in the wrapper element `<reuslt>` it is throwing error.

`[1.0-ml] XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND: let $SearchOption := <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"><term><term-option>case-insensitive</term-option><term-option>wildcarded</term-option><term-option>stemmed</term-option><term-option>diacritic-insensitive</term-option><term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option></term><debug>true</debug></options> let $search := search:search("multilayers", $SearchOption, 1, 10) return <result>{ for $searchResult in $search/search:result let $docUri := $searchResult/@uri return let $document := fn:doc($docUri) return cts:highlight($document, "multilayers", <hilighted-text>{ $cts:text }</hilighted-text>) }</result>`

-- element nodes cannot have document node children

below is the code:

xquery version "1.0-ml";

```
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

let $SearchOption := <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
                            <term>
                                <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
                                <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
                                <term-option>stemmed</term-option>
                                <term-option>diacritic-insensitive</term-option>
                                <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
                            </term>
              <debug>true</debug>
                        </options>
let $search := search:search('multilayers',$SearchOption,1,10)
return

  <result>{
          for $searchResult in $search/search:result
          let $docUri := $searchResult/@uri
          return
                (
                     let $document := fn:doc($docUri)
                      return
                      cts:highlight($document, "multilayers", <hilighted-text>{$cts:text}</hilighted-text>)                     
                )

 }</result>
```

Comment: Did you try `cts:highlight($document/node(), ...` yet?

Answer (score 0):

(turning comment into a proper answer)

The root cause is that you are feeding a document-node into the cts:highlight function, and apparently it finds a match at top-level in your case. It sounds a bit odd, but it tries to put that top-level node in a `hilighted-text` element, but that is not allowed in XML.

The simple solution is to pass in the root-element, rather than the document-node itself, by using `$document/node()`, rather than `$document`.

HTH!